# Violation of PRIMARY KEY when trying to update entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to update an Entity in my database, but when I try to do so I get an error saying `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Units'.  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Units'.`

I am not trying to insert new data with a key that already exists.  I am merely trying to retrieve an already existing item from the database, modify it, and then update it.

Here, is the code that does this:

```
// Get an already existing unit from the repository
Unit existingUnit = pacificRepo.GetUnit(unit.c_number);

// Update a few values of this existing unit
existingUnit.serial_number = unit.serial_number;
existingUnit.country = unit.country;
existingUnit.geo_location = unit.geo_location;

// Commit the changes to the repository
pacificRepo.UpdateUnit(existingUnit);
```

The supporting GetUnit() function used above is very simple:

```
public Unit GetUnit(string c_number)
{
    return context.Units.FirstOrDefault(u => u.c_number == c_number);
}
```

Here is the offending function:

```
public bool UpdateUnit(Unit u)
{
    try
    {
        context.Entry(u).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;  // Violation of PRIMARY KEY ....
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**:  Here is the Unit class

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    public string c_number { get; set; }
    public string serial_number { get; set; }
    public string ip_address { get; set; }
    public string build_version { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public DbGeography geo_location { get; set; }
    public string location_at_address { get; set; }
    public int deployment_status { get; set; }
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public int contact_id { get; set; }
    public int reg_contact_id { get; set; }
    public int network_id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Units] (
[c_number]            NVARCHAR (45)     NOT NULL,
[serial_number]       NVARCHAR (45)     NULL,
[ip_address]          NVARCHAR (45)     NOT NULL,
[build_version]       NVARCHAR (45)     NOT NULL,
[geo_location]        [sys].[geography] NULL,
[location_at_address] NVARCHAR (45)     NULL,
[deployment_status]   INT               NOT NULL,
[short_description]   NVARCHAR (255)    NULL,
[notes]               TEXT              NULL,
[contact_id]          INT               NULL,
[reg_contact_id]      INT               NULL,
[network_id]          INT               NULL,
[country]             NVARCHAR (45)     NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Units] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([c_number] ASC)
);
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  I am not trying to Add() it, I am trying to set its state to modified.

Comment: What does the key field in the `Unit` class look like?

Comment: updated my question to include this

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. If you have the option, don't make your primary key NVARCHAR(45), especially if it is actually a number as implied by the name `c_number` 2. Capture the SQL generated by your statement and post it. 3. Ensure there are no triggers on this table that may be causing the PK issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Your comment solved my issue. In my case, I had a trigger that was firing on update which caused a violation of the primary key in another table

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, try commenting out this line

```
context.Entry(u).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

You should not have to set the state, EF should be tracking it. Of course that assumes that the context doesn't go out of scope between retrieving the entity and updating it. If it does you'll need to retrieve the `Units` object again in `UpdateUnit` and then apply the changes by transferring the values from the passed-in object into the retrieved object.

I'm curious though, this is the second time in two weeks I've seen code on SO where it is explicitly setting the `State` of the object. Is there an article or blog post that recently came out showing that you should do that or something?

Answer (score 0):

replace following line

```
context.Entry(u).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

with

```
context.Unit.Attach(u);
```

PS. Your entity is in `Detached` state probably.

User this resource for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx